# referencing problem in Bibtex

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibtex

I am using the reference BibTeX file as ref.bib, I am using \cite command to cite in the following latex environment

```
\documentclass[10pt,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{structure}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{bm}
```

and

```
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\bibliography{ref.bib}
\end{frame}
```

But I am not getting any reference in the pdf . Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle `(pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: I am using overleaf

Comment: The commands `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}` in the preamble and `\bibliography{ref.bib}` towards the end of the document are in direct conflict with each other. Be sure to (a) delete `\bibliography{ref.bib}` and to make sure that `bibliography.bib` contains all needed bibliographic entries.

Comment: Three other comments: (i) Don't load `hyperref` twice. (ii) Don't load `biblatex` twice. (iii) Since you employ `biblatex` with the options `natbib=true` and `style=authoryear`, you should  be using the `plainnat` bibliographystyle, *not* the `plain` bibliography style.

Comment: Replace `bibliography{ref.bib}` with  the normal (with biblatex) `\printbibliography`.

Comment: I did all you guy's suggestion, still not getting it....

Comment: Do you get any errors (which can be checked by clicking the icon next to the compile button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two incompatible methods to generate citations and a bibliography in LaTeX.

You have `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and `\bibliography{ref.bib}` in the document body, which are used to generate BibTeX-based bibliographies. (It doesn't matter on a current system, but technically `\bibliography{ref.bib}` is wrong. The file name argument to `\bibliography` must not include the file extension, so `\bibliography{ref}` would be correct).

But then you also load `biblatex` (twice! `\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,useprefix=true]{biblatex}` *and* `\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}`, load packages only once to avoid confusion and option conflicts) and use its commands `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}` (pointing to a different file than the `\bibliography`) and `\printbibliography`.

**`biblatex` and the BibTeX-based bibliography method are incompatible and you need to choose one of the two.**

---

### `biblatex`

If you choose `biblatex`, you need to remove all `\bibliographystyle` calls and you may not have a `\bibliography` call in the document body. (You can give the `.bib` file in a `\bibliography` call in the preamble, but it is recommended to use `\addbibresource` - where the file extension must be included).

Your `biblatex` document would look roughly like this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{structure}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,useprefix=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note, however, that it is strongly recommended to use Biber instead of BibTeX with `biblatex`. That should be as easy as changing `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,` and running Biber instead of BibTeX (or telling your editor to do that: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)).

---

### BibTeX

If you want to use BibTeX, remove all mentions of `biblatex` and its `\addbibresource` and `\printbibliography` commands. Instead use `\bibliographstyle` and `\bibliography`.

A BibTeX-based document would look like this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{structure}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\bibliographystyle{plain}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Lorem \cite{incollection-full}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Note that you should never load packages twice (in the question, `hyperref` and `biblatex` are loaded twice). In this case it is not necessary to load `hyperref` at all, since `biblatex` already takes care of that.