# bibliographystyle is not defined once I compile the latex file

Tags: biblatex, latex3

I need to use the following command as part of a guideline:

```
\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}
\bibliography{Reference.bib}
```

However, I am getting the following mistake:

```
! Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid.
```

Can you please help me identify how to resolve this issue? Below I attach all the packages that I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{rotating}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex}
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
%  andothers = {et al.},
%}
\usepackage[mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,authordate,giveninits=true, backend=biber, natbib,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% package for including graphics with figure-environment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{breqn}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue, urlcolor  = blue]{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}
\bibliography{Reference.bib}


\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
              singlelinecheck = false}

\usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{collcell}   
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{aliceblue}{rgb}{0.94, 0.97, 1.0}
\definecolor{beaublue}{rgb}{0.74, 0.83, 0.9}
           
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[automark]
  {scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\cfoot[]{\pagemark} 
\setheadsepline[122mm]{0.3mm}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{0.000}}}{#1}}    
%
\doublespacing
\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}%
  \@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that you are mixing bilatex and bibtex approaches to make a bibliography, what is wrong. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) to understand the basics of each approach.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554756/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46334/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226137/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420634/35864

Answer (score 2):

### `biblatex` and classical BibTeX's `\bibliographystyle` don't go together

In your preamble you have

```
\usepackage[mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,authordate,giveninits=true, backend=biber, natbib,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}
```

and then later on

```
\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}
\bibliography{Reference.bib}
```

This is a mix of two different approaches to generating citations and bibliographies in LaTeX: `biblatex` on the one hand and classical BibTeX on the other. You can find out much more about the differences at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) (an introduction to `biblatex` is at [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864)). Those two approaches are completely incompatible even if they share a few command names.

**`\bibliographystyle`** is a command from the BibTeX world and tells BibTeX about the bibliography style you want to use. `biblatex` has a different way to set up the bibliography style (mainly through its `style` option, but the wrapper package `biblatex-chicago` is special) and does not use `\bibliographystyle`. It explicitly redefines `\bibliographystyle` to throw an error, because use of that command indicates that part of your document is still in the classical BibTeX world.

Note that with `biblatex` the command **`\bibliography`** is used in the preamble (but it is preferable to use `\addbibresource`), whereas with classical BibTeX the command goes into the document body in the place where you want the final bibliography to appear. In any case, the argument of `\bibliography` should be the name of your `.bib` file *without* file extension (even though most modern systems will still find the file even if you erroneously include the extension): `\bibliography{References}`.

You haven't shared the document body with us, so we don't really have a chance to guess which of the two approaches you may want to use. In any case you will have to decide whether to use `biblatex` or classical BibTeX in your document.

### Using `biblatex`

If you want to use `biblatex` or specifically `biblatex-chicago`, just get rid of the line `\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}` and change `\bibliography{Reference.bib}` to

```
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}
```

Then use

```
\printbibliography
```

in the document body to produce a bibliography.

Note that you need to compile your document with Biber instead of BibTeX (a full compile cycle would at least be LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX - where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for what Biber does (the explanations for BibTeX apply to Biber as well) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help with making your editor run Biber for you.

Note further that classical BibTeX's `.bst` styles are incompatible with `biblatex`, so there is no way to use `spmpsci` with `biblatex`. (There are some `biblatex` implementations of popular styles and a number of other third-party styles, but generally speaking there rarely are `biblatex` versions of BibTeX journal styles).

### Using BibTeX

If you want to use classical BibTeX (with the style `spmpsci`), get rid of

```
\usepackage[mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,authordate,giveninits=true, backend=biber, natbib,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}
```

Remove

```
\bibliography{Reference.bib}
```

from the preamble and add

```
\bibliography{Reference}
```

in your document body where you want the bibliography to show up.

You then compile this document with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).